# Как вывести все записи за определённый день?

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Нужно вывести все записи за определённый день. Например, за 12 число текущего месяца текущего года.
Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: @lostelle, а создать столбец в таблице, в который при создании записи будет добавляться дата, не пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас же есть поле даты для Вашей записи, да? Если нет, то его надо завести (как Вам уже подсказал [[@intro94](/users/17721/intro94)](/users/17721/intro94)), а затем воспользоваться [функциями работы с датой/временем](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Для описанной задачи нужна функция [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff). Пусть поле с датой называется `date_create`, чтобы найти все записи за 12 число текущего месяца и года, нужно в условие добавить

```
DATEDIFF(date_create, '2014-08-12') = 0
```

Comment: Зачем извращаться и функцию использовать в условии?
Не проще использовать прямое сравнение типа date_create = @Date

Comment: @namak7, Ваша правда. Только если поле `date_create` имеет тип `DATETIME` его нужно будет скастить до `DATE`?

Comment: Ну да, тут, конечно, тип date или datetime надо учитывать.